# action.url doesn't seem to run

Tags: odoo, odoo-14

I have this action server:

```
def obtener_todos_los_adjuntos_en_un_zip(self):
        
        tab_id = []
        
        for invoice in self:
            tab_id.append(invoice.id)

        base_url = self.env['ir.config_parameter'].get_param('web.base.url')

        url = f'{base_url}/web/binary/descargar_adjuntos?ids={"-".join(str(x) for x in tab_id)}'
        
        return {
            "type": "ir.actions.act_url",
            "url": url,
            "target": "new",
        }
```

In my xml:

```
<odoo>

    <record id="account_move_action_server"
        model="ir.actions.server">
        <field name="name">Descargar todos los adjuntos</field>
        <field name="model_id"
            ref="model_account_move" />
        <field name="binding_model_id"
            ref="model_account_move" />
        <field name="state">code</field>
        <field name="code">
        if records:
            records.obtener_todos_los_adjuntos_en_un_zip()
            
        </field>
    </record>

</odoo>
```

But it is not doing anything with the url passed to it. What do I need to do to make this action.url work?

Answer (score 1):

So I need to return to a "action" var:

```
<odoo>

    <record id="account_move_action_server"
        model="ir.actions.server">
        <field name="name">Descargar todos los adjuntos</field>
        <field name="model_id"
            ref="model_account_move" />
        <field name="binding_model_id"
            ref="model_account_move" />
        <field name="state">code</field>
        <field name="code">
        if records:
            action = records.obtener_todos_los_adjuntos_en_un_zip()
            
        </field>
    </record>

</odoo>
```

From [odoo docs](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/15.0/developer/reference/backend/actions.html#state-fields):

> The code segment can define a variable called action, which will be >returned to the client as the next action to execute:

```
<record model="ir.actions.server" id="print_instance">
    <field name="name">Res Partner Server Action</field>
    <field name="model_id" ref="model_res_partner"/>
    <field name="state">code</field>
    <field name="code">
        if record.some_condition():
            action = {
                "type": "ir.actions.act_window",
                "view_mode": "form",
                "res_model": record._name,
                "res_id": record.id,
            }
    </field>
</record>
```

> will ask the client to open a form for the record if it fulfills some condition